# use text-overflow and display:flex in <img>

Tags: css

I have `img` and I want if the image can't load, the alt appears in the middle of the image and if it's too big it becomes an `ellipsis` and it should be on one line

```css
img { 
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #111;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color:#fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
```

please no `margin` , `padding` or `line-height` tricks i can't use any of them because the `img` height is `100%` i can't know what is the final height

the code for firefox only so it must work in newest firefox version

Comment: so it seems like you already have what you need, as it appears with your css as it desired to be,  where is the problem then ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a pseudo element for this:

```css
img { 
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:#fff;
  position: relative;
  resize: both; /* resize the image to see the effect */
}
img:before {
  content: attr(alt);
  position: absolute;
  /* this will center the element */
  inset: 0;
  height: min-content;
  max-width: min-content;
  margin: auto;
  /**/
  border-image: linear-gradient(#111 0 0) fill 0//100vw; /* a trick that will make sure the color covers all the area outside the element */
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
```

Comment: i need it to work in firefox

Comment: @FireGamer updated

Comment: it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `display: inline-block` to your image and it will work.

This won't center the text though and won't hide the broken image icon.

```css
img { 
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #111;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color:#fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
```

Comment: *I want if the image can't load, the alt appears in the middle of the image*

Comment: the text not in the middle and it don't work in firefox